# Swapping SD cards between RPi4 and RPi3b

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, pi-4

I have an RPi3b that is used as a NAS and a RPi4 that is used as a sensor monitor.

I want to use the RPi4 as a NAS due to its better performance.

Considering both systems are on Raspbian Buster (10), can I just swap the microSD cards between the two, considering that the RPi3b is Buster and should have the RPi4 required firmware?

Comment: Any Buster 2020-08-20 SDCard will boot on ANY Raspberry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Raspberry Pi operating system will boot on all Raspberry Pis released at or before the OS. So it should not be a problem to boot the [Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/) on a RPi3B and a RPi4. The image contains different kernel and firmware to make this possible:

```
rpi ~$ ls -1 /boot/kernel*
/boot/kernel7.img
/boot/kernel7l.img
/boot/kernel8.img
/boot/kernel.img
```

In [Boot options in config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/boot.md) you find:

> **kernel**
> kernel is the alternative filename on the boot partition to use when loading the kernel. The default value on the Pi 1, Pi Zero, and Compute Module is kernel.img, and on the Pi 2, Pi 3, and Compute Module 3 it is kernel7.img. On the Pi4, it is kernel7l.img.
>
> **arm_64bit**
> If set to non-zero, forces the kernel loading system to assume a 64-bit kernel, starts the processors up in 64-bit mode, and sets kernel8.img to be the kernel image loaded, unless there is an explicit kernel option defined in which case that is used instead. Defaults to 0 on all platforms. NOTE: 64-bit kernels must be uncompressed image files.
>
> Note that the 64-bit kernel will only work on the Pi4, Pi3, and Pi2B rev1.2 boards with latest firmware.